# Using scp with a forwarded ssh agent

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I'm currently trying to `scp` a file from one server to another, using an ssh key on my local computer.

this is the command I'm currently using:

```
sudo scp -r -o "ForwardAgent yes" <new_folder> <second-server-path>
```

and I've followed [this github doc](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) to verify that my ssh agent is being forwarded to the second server's terminal.

`-o "ForwardAgent yes"` comes from [this reference](http://linux-tips.com/t/agent-forwarding-with-scp/292), but does not appear on my `man scp` reference.

However, after all this, the command still asks for a password (which we are trying to avoid). Any ideas on how to use the ssh forwarding?

Comment: can you access via ssh to the second server without password ?

Comment: I can access the terminal of both servers from my own computer without a password. However, I am running into these issues between copying a file from one server to another @WissamAl-Roujoulah

Comment: check the user that you are trying to use on the remote server and make sure that is the same use that you added a ssh key for it when you copy the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `scp` [does not support to forward your agent](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L397) (hardcoded to be disabled in the code) so this is not possible what you are trying.
- The problem is in `sudo`. Connection to `ssh-agent` is stored in environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` (`echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`) and this variable is not preserved during the `sudo` so there are two possibilities:

  - Do not use `sudo` to `scp`. Run just `scp` to some sane location and then `sudo cp` the file to the desired location.
  - Force `sudo` to preserve env. variables using the `-E` switch:

    ```
    sudo scp -r <new_folder> <second-server-path>
    ```
- When you want to copy the file between two servers, use `-3` switch, which will make both authentications from your host, where you have access to your agent.

Comment: "*When you want to copy the file between two servers, use -3 switch, which will make both authentications from your host, where you have access to your agent.*" according to the man page, there is no -3 option. Only 1,2,4 or 6.

Comment: @SachaVorbeck It probably means that you have very old OpenSSH version. Try to update.

Comment: `-3`      *Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local
             host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between
             the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the
             progress meter.* It's not properly what @efong5 is trying to achieve but..

Answer (score 4):

With OpenSSH 8.4 (released 2020-09-27) support for agent forwarding was added to scp and sftp.

https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.4

> - scp(1), sftp(1): allow the -A flag to explicitly enable agent
>   forwarding in scp and sftp. The default remains to not forward an
>   agent, even when ssh_config enables it.

**Warning!** Using agent forwarding is a security issue, when the jump host is compromised or when you are affected from a mitm attack.

If you are using a jump host to copy files from your local machine to an internal network, it is better to use ProxyJump instead of agent forwarding, because the connection to the destination server is end to end encrypted and the jump host can not access your agent or read the data.

Example scp command using a jump host:

```
scp -o 'ProxyJump your.jump.host' myfile.txt remote.internal.host:/my/dir
```

**Update:**

Agent forwarding for scp and sftp was added to OpenSSH 8.4 for remote to remote file transfers.

In the past you had to provide credentials on the first host or you had to route the traffic through your local machine.

Now with OpenSSH 8.4 scp and sftp are capable of agent forwarding.

```
scp -A user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```