# scp: Copy files between two servers without routing through my machine

Tags: ssh, security, scp, file-copy

I have two servers `server1` and `server2`.

I am able to ssh into both servers from my machine using `ssh root@server1` or `ssh root@server2` with key login.

I want to copy a file from `server1` to `server2`.

Constraints:

1. I do not want to store private keys for ssh on either server. Nor should I be promted for a password.
2. I do not want to route the data via my machine. So can't use the `-3` option

This is the output I get:

```
$ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@server1:~/script.sh root@server2:~/

Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Verbose output:

```
$ scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@server1:~/script.sh root@server2:~/

Executing: /usr/bin/ssh '-x' '-oClearAllForwardings=yes' '-n' '-v' '-o' 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' '-l' 'root' '--' 'server1' 'scp -v' '~/script.sh' 'root@server2:~/'
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/johndoe/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/johndoe/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server1 [11.22.33.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/johndoe/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/johndoe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server1:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dS7************************************************Dw
debug1: Host 'server1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/johndoe/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:gw*******************************bc /home/johndoe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server1 ([11.22.33.44]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v ~/script.sh root@server2:~/
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host server2, user root, command scp -v -t ~/
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server2 [55.66.77.88] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server2:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:pj***************************************eA
debug1: Host 'server2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2780, received 7200 bytes, in 1.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2501.1, received 6477.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Note:

1. I have my public key configured in the `authorized_keys` files of each server.
2. I have my private key saved as `id_rsa` in `.ssh` directory of my machine only.
3. OS on my machine and `server2` is Ubuntu 18.04 and that on `server1` is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you running `ssh-agent`? If yes, you can use `ssh -A` to forward your agent to the server you're connecting to.

Comment: I am not using it at present. But I can start using it. How would I use it with `scp` instead of `ssh`? Does it copy over the certificates to the server? If so, is it temporary or persistent?

Comment: Start it on your local machine and add your private key to the agent. When you connect with `ssh -A`, your private key will be kept in memory on the remote server. You can then use it to `scp` from server1 to server2.

Comment: Hmm..but I do not wan't to start a ssh session. (scp may internally do that). I guess, I am asking for too much.

Comment: @Dojo : Did you verify your permission for authorized_keys file , it should be rw-r-----     ( 640 )

Comment: `scp` does not support agent forwarding – See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327085/119732 – You might be able to bypass that with use of `-S` and smart script that strips the `-oForwardAgent=no` – But may there's a deeper reason why the option is disabled in the first place.

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar It was 600 as is the recommendation. Changed it to 640 but still the same.

Comment: @Dojo : Ohh , 600 was to .ssh directory and 640 for authorized_keys i think.. but anyhow , it doesn't make any change for yours ...so might be some other issue...